# Mongo: Query to get count of objects in a nested field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I needed some help to create a count query on nested objects in a field, across all documents. Each document json has a many fields. One particular field called "hotlinks" comprises of many internal dynamic object fields.

```
Doc1:
{
  hotlinks : { 112222:{....} , 333333: {.....} , 545555: {.....}      }
}

Doc2:
{
  hotlinks : { 67756:{....} , 756767: {.....} , 1111111: {.....}      }
}
```

Each document has a hotlinks fields. The hotlinks field comprises of varied inner hotlink objects. Each key is a java unique id and has objects that contain data (inner fields).

I needed a way to get the count of all the inner nested objects of the field – ‘hotlinks’.
For example the summation of inner objects of hotlinks in doc1 and doc2 would be 6.

Is there any way to do this via a single query to get the count across all documents.

Thanks a lot,
Karan

Comment: Without using mapreduce functionality, I'm pretty sure you'd have to simply iterate over the cursor and "manually" count the occurrences within the sub-document.

Comment: The most efficient would be to store the count when you save or modify the document

Comment: Unfortunately as of 2.4 there is no ability to do this using the aggregation framework. If you hotlinks had been in an array you could have used $unwind and $sum to calculate the totals but in this case you'll have to use mapReduce or do it in the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may not be the best approach, but you can define a javascript variable and sum up the counts. i.e;

```
var hotlinkTotal=0;
db.collection.find().forEach(function(x){hotlinkTotal+=x.hotlinks.length;});
print(hotlinkTotal);
```

Comment: Yep - if not this way, a mapreduce operation would be the other alternative.

Comment: Hi Lix And Erdimeola, Thanks so much for your reply. I have thousands of documents in my collection. Thus i need a fast and efficient way to get the count. I feel the javascript way would be a heavy operation. Would mapreduce be efficient... Thanks so much, Karan

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 3):

Quite possible if using MongoDB 3.6 and newer though the aggregation framework.
Use the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator within an aggregation pipeline to convert the document to an array. The return array contains an element for each field/value pair in the original document. Each element in the return array is a document that contains two fields `k` and `v`.

On getting the array, you can then leverage the use of the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)** operator which returns the number of elements in the given array thus giving you the count per document.

Getting the count across all the documents requires a [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline where you specify the `_id` key of null or a constant value which gives calculates accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.

All this can be done in a single pipeline by nesting the expressions as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": {
            "$sum": { 
                "$size": { "$objectToArray": "$hotlinks" }
            }
        }
    } }     
])
```

**Example Output**

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "count" : 6
}
```

---